# 08P01: insufficient data left in message in custom mapping

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I'm writing a custom mapping for `pg_vector` extension, but I'm getting this error `08P01: insufficient data left in the message in custom mapping` whenever I try to write to the database.

I have a `psql (15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1))` database with an installed `pg_vector` extension.

I have a test database, `vectortest`, with test table `items` with a single field of type `vector(3)` which is more or less a float32 array.

```
  Column   |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 embedding | vector(3) |           |          |
```

I know for sure that it works. I could add new records with SQL

```cs
await using (var cmd = dataSource.CreateCommand("INSERT INTO items VALUES ('[1,2,3]')"))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have an implementation for `TypeHandlerResolverFactory` and `TypeHandlerResolver`, which return my custom handler `PgVectorTypeHandler : NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<Vector>`

The vector could be read and written to database as binary, it is basically `(ushort, ushort, float, float, ...)`

My mapping for read works great.

```cs
public override Vector Read(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, int len, FieldDescription? fieldDescription = null)
{
    var dim = buf.ReadUInt16();
    var unused = buf.ReadUInt16();

    var values = new float[dim];
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        values[i] = buf.ReadSingle();
    }
        
    return new Vector(values);
}
```

But my mapper for write failed with `08P01: insufficient data left in the message in custom mapping` exception and `FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 6` on server side.

```cs
public override void Write(Vector value, NpgsqlWriteBuffer buf, NpgsqlParameter? parameter)
{
    buf.WriteUInt16((ushort)value.Values.Length);
    buf.WriteUInt16(0);

    buf.WriteSingle(value.Values[0]); 
    buf.WriteSingle(value.Values[1]);
    buf.WriteSingle(value.Values[2]);
    // here was for-loop but I replaced it to simplify
}
```

This is how I execute the command

```cs
await using (var cmd = dataSource.CreateCommand("INSERT INTO items VALUES (@vec)"))
{
    var vector1 = new Vector(new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f });
    var par = cmd.CreateParameter();
    par.ParameterName = "vec";
    par.Value = vector1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(new Vector(new[] { 4f, 5f, 6f }));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I tried positional, named paramters - it does not matter. I'm out of ideas about where I should look and what I should check.

Comment: this error typically indicates an error in your type handler - can you point to your complete source code?

Comment: @ShayRojansky sure, here is a full handler implementation

https://github.com/xakpc/DotnetPrompt.Npgsql.PgVector/blob/main/src/DotnetPrompt.Npgsql.PgVector/Internal/PgVectorTypeHandler.cs

Comment: Seems like you're forgetting to actually write the length in WriteObjectWithLength - does that fix it?

Comment: @ShayRojansky, you meant to write the Int32 size of the byte array first? 

That helped! Thank you, Shay

Comment: I will wright an answer myself if you don't mind

Comment: Happy this solved the problem for you! We have some plans on simplifying the type handler model. This unfortunately might require you to update your handler for Npgsql 8.0, but it should at least be less complex/less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how `NpgsqlTypeHandler<T>` should be implemented.

NpgsqlTypeHandler, on top of Read/Write methods, wants you to implement two non-generic methods, `ValidateObjectAndGetLength` and `WriteObjectWithLength`.

I didn't get why we need `WriteObjectWithLength` and `Write` methods, but actually, **it's `WriteObjectWithLength` who called** by `NpgsqlCommand.Write`.

```
internal class PgVectorTypeHandler : NpgsqlTypeHandler<Vector>
{
    // WRONG IMPLEMENTATION
    public override Task WriteObjectWithLength(object? value, NpgsqlWriteBuffer buf, NpgsqlLengthCache? lengthCache,
        NpgsqlParameter parameter, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        Write(value as Vector ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("value type is invalid"), buf, lengthCache, parameter, async, cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    ...
}
```

But actually, that was not enough. My second mistake was that I didn't know **you should write Int32 (4 bytes) value with how many bytes your parameter value has**.

```cs
    // BETTER IMPLEMENTATION
    public override Task WriteObjectWithLength(object? value, NpgsqlWriteBuffer buf, NpgsqlLengthCache? lengthCache,
        NpgsqlParameter parameter, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var valueVector = value as Vector ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("value type is invalid");
        buf.WriteInt32(ValidateAndGetLength(valueVector, ref lengthCache, parameter)); // required
        Write(valueVector, buf, lengthCache, parameter, async, cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

And then, I started to explore a base `NpgsqlTypeHandler` class a little bit more and found out that there is an implementation that does the same thing, even better. So the best solution here

```cs
    // PROPER IMPLEMENTATION
    public override Task WriteObjectWithLength(object? value, NpgsqlWriteBuffer buf, NpgsqlLengthCache? lengthCache,
        NpgsqlParameter? parameter, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        return base.WriteWithLength(value as Vector, buf, lengthCache, parameter, async, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Same goes for length as well

```
    public override int ValidateObjectAndGetLength(object value, ref NpgsqlLengthCache? lengthCache, NpgsqlParameter? parameter)
    {
        return base.ValidateAndGetLength<Vector>(value as Vector, ref lengthCache, parameter);
    }
```

That will do some logic to write length inside and eventually call `Write` method to write only value.